# Is there a way to parallelize swig C file generation?

Tags: python, swig

We have a setup where we create a python interface to a C library. We are naively exposing every function, for a number of reasons, and while this is not optimal, it's the least bad solution for the time being.

Our swig interface file simply imports two dozen C header files, and we swig that, then compile, then link the results.

The problem is, that the compilation of the resulting C file is very slow, and by far the slowest step in our build process. We have highly parallel machines, so it would be nice to split this up.

The problem is, when making multiple interface files, compiling them to object files works well, but during the final linking, the linker (rightfully) complains that:

```
foo1.c:9147: multiple definition of `PyInit__bar_lib'
foo2.c:74285: first defined here
```

Is there a way to split up swig'ging?

Comment: How slow (in seconds) is "very slow"? What is the size of generated wrapper code? Wrapping "two dozen C header files" does not sound like a serious job even for a poorly written codegen.

Comment: It takes roughly 30 seconds. Which, in the grand scheme of things, is not too bad, but annoying when the rest can be built in six and we build this many times per day as part of an automated testing setup.

Comment: Oh and to answer your other question: the wrapped code is roughly 3MB and 75k LOC.

Comment: If you like, you can group your functions and use a number of interface `.i` files (use different module names). They will each generate an interface. In the SWIG documentation, it is explained how to group multiple SWIG'ed libraries to a single type library

Comment: @JensMunk thanks for your answer. This works, but creates other problems, chiefly the fact that now I have multiple name spaces and multiple python imports, which I'd prefer to avoid. Do you have a link to somewhere describing how to group multiple SWIG'ed libraries into a single type library?

Comment: @bolind The trick is to have multiple modules share the `SWIG` run time. It is section 16.3 in SWIG 3.0 documentation.